# FPDF Character encoding

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf

I've seen many question on SO about generating PDFs in PHP with help of FPDF and also many problems with encoding. My native language is Slovak, so far I found out that I should be using ISO-8859-2 encoding. I tried converting UTF-8 to ISO-8859-2 through

```
iconv('utf-8', 'ISO-8859-2', $text)
```

but fpdf throws error that it can't recognize some characters.

I am trying to generate some text like this

```
$pdf->Cell(0, 0, self::text('ZÁKAZNÍK'), '', '', 'L');


    function text($text)
    {
//        return $text;
//        return mb_convert_encoding($text, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
        return iconv('utf-8', 'cp1252', html_entity_decode($text));
    }
```

Any idea? It should work for characters like (ľščťžýáíéôúä)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

`iconv('UTF-8','iso-8859-2//TRANSLIT//IGNORE',$text);`

That should work.

Comment: no, still not working. And I had one successful attempt, when using translit but I do not want to use transliteration because it can change the meaning of word by 180 degrees so that's a bit dangerous:)

Comment: ISO-8859-2 has all the Slovakian characters, so it is impossible that translit would change properly written Slovakian text in UTF8 to something different, if it still doesn't work, your font is not containing those characters, and you got to import a proper font by yourself via `$fpdf->AddFont()`. There is no other way.

Comment: your comment about using AddFont helped me, although I also used tFPDF instead of original fpdf implementation